# Is <stdio.h> include needed for FILE in C?

Tags: c, file, include, syntax-error

I have a header file (sample.h) for my c file (sample.c). When I prototyped a function in my header file as below.

```
return_type sample_fun (FILE *filePtr);
```

I get a compilation error saying, `Syntax error: possible missing ')' or ','?` When I include the stdio.h error is resolved. Is the stdio.h include mandatory? Some of my files work well without the include.

I use gcc on AIX.

Comment: `FILE` type is defined in `stdio.h`.

Comment: Which files work well without it?  Probably, those files include some other header which includes stdio.h.

Comment: @Will Yes, they might as they include a lot of header files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the type `FILE` is defined in `stdio.h`; if you mention it, then you must include that file.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. `FILE` is `typedef`ed from a `struct iobuf` on most platforms. This requires that the full definition of `struct iobuf` be present, even though all the interfaces use `FILE *`, and pointer types do not normally require full definitions prior to their use (C limitation).

See this question for more information: [Forward declare FILE *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882346/forward-declare-file)