# forward declaration of C structure in C++

Tags: c++, c, struct, compatibility, forward-declaration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Forward declare FILE *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882346/forward-declare-file)

Suppose I want to write a wrapper class for C struct that is accest by a pointer to it such as FILE

in C you have to say

```
typedef struct _iobuf
    {
    /*content of this struct*/
    } FILE;
```

to get rid of the struct in object declarations. Now I want to do the following in filec.h:

```
class FILE;

class FileC
    {
    public:
        FileC(const char* name,const char* mode);
        ~FileC();
    private:
        FILE* fptr;
    };
```

And in filec.cpp:

```
#include "filec.h"
#include <cstdio>

//Implementation of FileC member functions
```

But when compiling I just get complaints about incomplete type struct FILE. Switching include order give that FILE already has been declared. I can solve it by using implementation specific details or use a void* instead FILE* casting back and forth. But how to do it nicely? Using iostream is not an answer because it also includes stdio anyway.

Comment: FILE is a struct, but you forward declare as class.

Comment: The forward declaration should be `struct FILE` why it is `class FILE`?

Comment: Slight aside, you could use pimpl idiom.

Comment: Maybe try `extern "C" struct FILE;`, to get the name mangling right.

Comment: @KerrekSB, no, type names are not mangled, `extern "C"` does nothing for types, only "function types, function names with external linkage, and variable names with external linkage have a
_language linkage_" [dcl.link]/1

Comment: @nhahtdh: If `FILE` were a `struct`, then it would be fine to declare it using `class`; the keywords are equivalent in declarations. However, it's not a class at all; it's a `typedef`, which can't be forward declared.

Comment: Use pimpl idiom to avoid using the C include in the client code