# Predeclare tagged struct

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Some C include files uses following convention:

```
typedef struct YOUSHALLNOTUSETHISNAME
    {
//  members
    } USETHISNAME;
```

How should I the predeclare USETHISNAME in this case? Break the convention and say

```
typedef struct YOUSHALLNOTUSETHISNAME USETHISNAME;
```

The problem is that I cannot control the header defining the struct. And I do not want to include the header defining the struct, since in this case it is a real beast: `windows.h`

Note:

This question is closely related to [Forward declare FILE *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882346/forward-declare-file).

Comment: That seems fine: you're using the not-to-be-used name once only, and inside (presumably) the same header file, so it won't be used anywhere outside that header file anyway. It's the latter that's really the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Improving on [Gopi's deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27796264/841108):

```
 typedef struct YOUSHALLNOTUSETHISNAME {
   // some fields
 } USETHISNAME;
 #define YOUSHALLNOTUSETHISNAME %%%some@thing!bad$for*the^C%compiler
```

Then most further occurrences of `YOUSHALLNOTUSETHISNAME` would be rejected, but a naughty developer could still later:

```
 #undef YOUSHALLNOTUSETHISNAME
```

BTW, if you don't want to define the fields of `struct YOUSHALLNOTUSETHISNAME` (which should be provided by another header) you could just

```
  typedef struct YOUSHALLNOTUSETHISNAME USETHISNAME;
```

Also, are you sure to want to avoid `#include <windows.h>`? Maybe you just need precompiled headers. Some compilers provide that feature.

---

However, I believe it is more a social issue than only a technical one. You should *document* that people should *not use* `YOUSHALLNOTUSETHISNAME`

Comment: This answer applies if I were the author of the header. But I am not, and I commit an error when I using the internal name.